# Configuring logging for ActiveMQ 5.5 on Tomcat 6 with web app using SLF4j and logback

Tags: tomcat6, activemq-classic, slf4j, logback

I would like my web app to log using SLF4j and logback. However, I am using ActiveMQ - which then requires that some if its jars go in /usr/share/tomcat6/lib (this is because the queues are defined outside of the web app so the classes to support them must be at container level).
ActiveMQ 5.5+ requires SLF4j-api so that jar has to go in to. Because SLF4j is now starting it needs to have a logging library added or it will simply nop. Thus, logback-core and logback-classic go in too.

After quite some frustration I got this working well enough that I can tidy it up shortly. I needed to configure logback to use a JNDI lookup to get the context. Then it can lookup logback-kenobi.xml in my web app and have a separate configuration there.

However, I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this. For one, the context handling appears not to support the groovy format. I did have a logback.groovy in my web app that logged to console when I was developing locally (which means that Eclipse WTP works nicely) but logs to file and to Splunk Storm when everywhere else. I'm going to want to do something similar with this setup but I'm not sure if I should do that by overwriting the logback-kenobi.xml or some other method.

Note that I don't, currently, need Tomcat itself to log with slf4j although I am planning to do that. Nor do I really need ActiveMQ to log with slf4j but I did need it to stop spewing debug messages every 30s as it was doing. I am aware of [tomcat-slf4j-logbak](https://github.com/grgrzybek/tomcat-slf4j-logback) but I don't believe it is directly useful as it is ActiveMQ requiring logging which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this.

Best is an opinion, working is a fact.